# How do find $\lfloor n\sqrt 7 \rfloor$ without a calculator

Tags: elementary-number-theory

For all positive integers, $n$, define $t_n = \lfloor n\sqrt 7 \rfloor$. I am trying to find a way to compute the  values $t_n$ without squaring "large numbers" or taking square roots to more than the first few significant digits. The first 20 values are

| n | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 | 6 | 7 | 8 | 9 | 10 | 11 | 12 | 13 | 14 | 15 | 16 | 17 | 18 | 19 | 20 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| $t_n$ | 2 | 5 | 7 | 10 | 13 | 15 | 18 | 21 | 23 | 26 | 29 | 31 | 34 | 37 | 39 | 42 | 44 | 47 | 50 | 52 |

1. The OEIS says that this is a Beatty sequence. A consequence of that is, if $s=\sqrt 7$ and $t$ satisfies $\frac 1s + \frac 1t = 1$, then the images of the sequences $\{ns\}_{n=1}^\infty$ and $\{nt\}_{n=1}^\infty$ have no points in common and their union is the set of positive integers. I couldn't find a way to exploit that.
2. I also noticed that if $p$ is a common divisor of $n$ and of $t_n$, then $t_{n/p} = (t_n)/p$. But this is pointing in the wrong direction.
3. Also, since $2 < \sqrt 7 < 3$, then $t_{n+1} \in \{t_n + 2, t_n + 3 \}$. But I haven't figured out a simple way to decide which of the two is the correct value.

### added 9/24/2021

I have worked out a partial answer which I will describe below.

---

**Theorem.** Let $A$ and $B$ be positive rational numbers, Let $n$ be a positive integer and let $p$ be a square-free positive integer. If $A < x < B$, then
$$ pn^2+AB < (A+B)n\sqrt p < pn^2 + AB + \dfrac 14(B-A)^2 $$
and, if $(B-A)^2 \le 4$,
$$ \lfloor (A+B)n\sqrt p \rfloor =  pn^2+AB$$

---

***Proof**

Suppose $A < n\sqrt p < B$.

For positive, rational numbers, $A$ and $B$, and for positive integer, $n$, consider the inverted parabola

$$y = (x-A)(B-x) = -x^2+(A+B)x - AB$$

[image]

For $A < x < B$, this function is positive valued with a max value of
$y_{max} = \dfrac 14(B-A)^2$ occurring at $x_{max}= \dfrac 12(A+B)$. It follows that

$$ 0 < (n\sqrt p - A)(B - \sqrt p) \lt y_{max} $$

We do not have to say $``\le"$ because $x = n\sqrt p$ is an irrational number and $x_{max}$ is a rational number. We continue.

$$ 0 < -pn^2 + (A+B)n\sqrt p -AB < \dfrac 14(B-A)^2 $$

$$ pn^2+AB < (A+B)n\sqrt p < pn^2 + AB + \dfrac 14(B-A)^2 $$

If $\dfrac 14(B-A)^2 \le 1$, it follows that
$$\lfloor (A+B)n\sqrt p \rfloor = pn^2+AB$$

So, for example, we know that $ 52 < 20\sqrt 7 < 53$.
Letting $A=52$, $B=53$, $p=7$, and $n=20$, we find that

$$ 5556 < 2100\sqrt 7 < 5556\dfrac 14 $$

We find by computation that $2100\sqrt 7 \approx 5556.077753$.

It follows immediately that

\begin{align}
   \lfloor 2100\sqrt 7 \rfloor &=  5556 \\
   \lfloor 4200\sqrt 7 \rfloor &= 11112\\
   \lfloor 6300\sqrt 7 \rfloor &= 16668 \\
   \lfloor 8400\sqrt 7 \rfloor &= 22224 \\
\end{align}

Comment: Do you want to be able to compute $t_n$ without knowing $t_1,\ldots,t_{n-1}$? Or do you want to generate the numbers sequentially?

Comment: @TonyK : I was hoping to find $t_n$ as a function of the previous one or two terms.

Comment: Then you are going to have to compute $7n^2$. Does that count as a "large number"? (You don't have to take any square roots.)

Comment: @TonyK : It certainly does.  I was kind of wishing I could find a trick to avoid the squaring.

Comment: Are you doing this by hand? Or is $n$ in the millions? If the answer to both these questions is No, then I don't see a problem.

Comment: If you multiply by $\frac{n+1}{n}$ you'll be just over $1$ off at most. So then it becomes a guess of when to subtract $1$

Comment: @tonyK : I don't either. I really wish I could avoid the $7n^2$ but I don't see any way around it.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you compute a [continued fraction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continued_fraction) approximation $\sqrt 7 \approx \frac pq$, then for a while, you can compute $\lfloor n \sqrt 7\rfloor$ by computing $\lfloor \frac{pn}{q}\rfloor$ instead. This is very quick if we're computing the entire sequence: if we know $\hat t_n = \lfloor \frac{pn}{q}\rfloor$ and saved the value of $r_n = pn \bmod q$, then
$$
   r_{n+1} = r_n + p \bmod q\qquad \text{ and } \qquad \hat t_{n+1} = t_n + \left\lfloor\frac{r_n + p}{q}\right\rfloor = \hat t_n + \frac{p + r_n - r_{n+1}}{q}.
$$
Even if you want just one term $t_n$, $\lfloor \frac{pn}{q}\rfloor$ is not too terrible to compute - it's just that computing the entire sequence $t_1, t_2, \dots, t_n$ is where the approximation really shines.

---

However, at some point, the approximation stops working.

In general, we can guarantee that $\lfloor \frac{pn}{q}\rfloor = \lfloor n\sqrt 7\rfloor$ for $n < q$. That's because $|\frac pq - \sqrt 7| < \frac1{q^2}$ for all continued fraction approximations, so $|\frac{pn}{q} - n\sqrt 7| < \frac{n}{q^2} < \frac1q$. As long as $\frac{pn}{q}$ is not an integer, it will be at least $\frac 1q$ away from the nearest integer, and $n\sqrt 7$ is closer than that.

So all you have to do to compute the sequence $t_n$ is to keep computing better and better continued fraction approximations to $\sqrt 7$. We have
$$
   \sqrt 7 = 2 + \cfrac1{1 + \cfrac1{1 + \cfrac 1{1 + \cfrac1{4 + \dotsb}}}}
$$
and the block $1,1,1,4$ repeats forever; in continued fraction notation, $\sqrt 7 = [2; \overline{1,1,1,4}]$. There is a recursive formula for the $n^{\text{th}}$ continued fraction approximation: starting from $\frac{p_{-2}}{q_{-2}} = \frac 01$ and $\frac{p_{-1}}{q_{-1}} = \frac10$, we have $$\frac{p_n}{q_n} = \frac{a_n p_{n-1} + p_{n-2}}{a_n q_{n-1} + q_{n-2}}$$ where $a_n$ is the $n^{\text{th}}$ term of the periodic sequence $2, 1, 1, 1, 4, 1, 1, 1, 4, \dots$. To check yourself, the next few fractions you get are $$\frac 21, \frac31, \frac52, \frac83, \frac{37}{14}, \frac{45}{17}, \dots$$

Since the denominators $q_n$ grow exponentially, you will not have to do this very often if you want to compute your sequence; to compute $t_1, t_2, \dots, t_n$, you'll only need to update the continued fraction $O(\log n)$ times. (You could also begin by finding a continued fraction approximation $\sqrt 7 \approx \frac pq$ where $q$ is large enough to work for all the terms you want, then use that from the start.)